# "You've done very bad not to..." How to make it sound natural

Tags: phrase-request

In Spanish people sometimes say (literally):

> You've done very bad not to come and visit me...

Basically, in a very cordial manner, meaning that someone shouldn't have second guessed to come and visit them, that they would've loved it and that the next time, they should just do it without any hesitations!

I'm wondering how can one say that in English, and that it will sound natural to a native English speaker.

Comment: You might add the original Spanish phrase, as it is possible someone bilingual may have some additional insight. While your description is good, there are probably lots of ways to say this sort of thing.

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I should've. I just read your answer. :/ But tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a literal translation, but this expression is widely used:

> Don't be a stranger

If you want to imply a mild rebuke- that the other person did wrong by not coming sooner- you can say

> It was very remiss of you not to come and visit me.

[Remiss](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remiss?q=Remiss) means to fail in one's duty.

Answer (score 1):

> It's a shame that you didn't come and visit me.
>
> It's too bad that you didn't come and visit me.

And there are some related phrases like:

> I really missed you.
>
> There was a chocolate cake here waiting just for you.

Comment: I should have added more context, sorry. But the "There was a chocolate cake here waiting just for you." got me loling! :P "Don't be a stranger" is more along the lines of what I was looking for.